# Don't pause/affect particles with Time.timescale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script, where on `CollisionEnter2D` the particles are emitted from an object and the game pauses. The particles stop too. But I don't want to pause the particles. I want them to play even when the game is paused. How can I do this?

Here is a script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MovingPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float playerSpeed;
    public float maxPos = 2.7f;

    Vector3 position;
    public uiManager ui;

    Rigidbody2D rb;

    public GameObject particleSystemPrefab;

    void Awake ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        position = transform.position;
    }

    ......

    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "CubeObstacle") {
            foreach(ContactPoint2D contact in col.contacts)
            {
                Instantiate(particleSystemPrefab, contact.point, Quaternion.identity);
            }
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            ui.gameOverActivated();
            am.playerSound.Stop();
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", score);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the old days `ParticleSystem.Simulate` is used in the Update function but this was expensive. It slowed down many games.

Starting from *Unity 2017.1*, a new property [`ParticleSystem.MainModule.useUnscaledTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MainModule-useUnscaledTime.html) was added to fix this so that setting `Time.timescale` to `0` won't affect the particle if that's the behavior you prefer.

Simple Example:

```
ParticleSystem m_System = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
ParticleSystem.MainModule main = m_System.main;

//Use Unscaled Time
main.useUnscaledTime = true;
```

---

If you don't want to change it via code but through the Editor, it's the *Delta Time* drop-down option. Change it from *scaled* to *Unscaled*:

[image]

---

For your particular issue, change your `OnCollisionEnter2D` function to something below:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "CubeObstacle")
    {
        foreach (ContactPoint2D contact in col.contacts)
        {

            GameObject obj = Instantiate(particleSystemPrefab, contact.point, Quaternion.identity);
            ParticleSystem m_System = obj.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
            ParticleSystem.MainModule main = m_System.main;
            //Use Unscaled Time
            main.useUnscaledTime = true;

        }
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        ui.gameOverActivated();
        am.playerSound.Stop();
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", score);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title is a little confusing. You say "Time.timeScale = 0 don't pause particles" bu then your question says that you don't want to pause the particles when you set timeScale = 0... So I'm assuming that you want to play the particles even though you've set timeScale = 0. 
To have particle systems ignore timeScale, you use

`particleSystem.Simulate(Time.unscaledDeltaTime, true, false);`

Immediately after playing or enabling the particle system(s).
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Simulate.html